# R: Understanding K-Fold Validation Correctly?

Tags: r, validation, modeling, k-fold, predictive

Good Afternoon.

I wanted a sanity check after doing research about *k-Fold Cross-Validation*. I will provide my understanding, and then provide an example of how to execute the preconceived understanding in **R**.

I would really appreciate any help on if I'm thinking about this incorrectly, or if my code is not reflecting my thought process / the correct procedures. Take the basic predictive modeling scenario on a *continuous response variable*:

- Have a population dataset (xDF)
- I want to split the dataset into k=10 separate parts, train a model on 9 of them (binded), and then validate on the remaining validation set
- I then want to loop through each validation set to observe how the model performs on un-trained segments of the data
- Model performance measures (**RMSE** for this example) on the **kth**-fold validation set that display *similar results* on the **k+1...k+9th** validation set reveals that the model is well-generalized

R Code:

```
#Declaring randomly sampled validation indices

ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(xDF)), size = nrow(xDF))



n <- (nrow(xDF)/10)
nr <- nrow(xDF)
validation_ind <- split(ind, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))

#Looping through validation sets to obtain Model Performance measure of each set
RMSEsF <- double(10)
RMSEsFT <- double(10)
R2F <- double(10)
R2FT <- double(10)
rsq <- function (x, y) cor(x, y) ^ 2

for (i in 1:10){


    validate = as.data.frame(xDF[unlist(validation_ind[i]),])
    train = as.data.frame(xDF[unlist(validation_ind[-i]),])


    rf_train = randomForest(y~.,data=train,mtry=3)


    predictions_rf = predict(rf_train,validate)
    predictions_rft = predict(rf_train, train)


    RMSEsF[i] = RMSE(predictions_rf, validate$y)
    RMSEsFT[i] = RMSE(predictions_rft, train$y)
    R2F[i] = rsq(predictions_rf, validate$y)
    R2FT[i] = rsq(predictions_rft, train$y)

    print(".")


}

RMSEsF
RMSEsFT
```

Am I going about this correctly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: looks  ok... you can check against caret.. is there a larger question?

Comment: @StupidWolf - Not at the moment... apologies as this isn't a coding error, but more of a conceptual check.

Thank you for reviewing.